# How can springboot2 write data to two mysql database at the same time?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can springboot2 write data to two mysql database at the same time?
how should I configure my application.yaml?

Thanks!!

The springboot server can connect to two same DB(named a and b) and write data to them ,and the springboot server can read data from DB a.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the app for this, I think it will be a better approach to have the two databases mirrored

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple data sources, we need to declare multiple beans with different mappings within Spring's application context.

We can do this by using configuration classes:

```
@Configuration
public class TodoDatasourceConfiguration {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.todos")
public DataSourceProperties todosDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
 }
}

@Configuration
public class TopicDatasourceConfiguration {

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource.topics")
public DataSourceProperties topicsDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
 }

}
```

see more : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-multiple-datasources